# Heat map and visualization

Tags: visualization

I want to create a heat map to visualize some production data, but without geolocation. I am finishing some experiments in a greenhouse, divided in different sectors. The idea is to make a heat map to watch in which areas we are harvesting more fruits, or less, in each season.

Which tool, software or language do you think is better for this purpose? I was looking for information, but the main tools are for geolocation.

Comment: It should be easy enough to create a heat map using Python's matplotlib library using the "go.heatmap" function. I have also created heat maps using Matlab and imagine that its simple to do in languages like R too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the simplest is to use `Seaborn`. Check out the example below:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns 

sns.set()
np.random.seed(0)

uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data)
```

And the output looks as follows:

[image]

This is taken from the seaborn [documentation](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ***Seaborn*** for this purpose.

```
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
sn.heatmap(cm,annot=True)
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]